Inconsistent solutions with FindRoot
I have a 3 component parametric function with randomly generated parameters:
    function = {Sqrt[(0. + 0.75764 t - 0.615051 Sin[2 t])^2 + (0. + 0.429824 t + 
    0.218389 Sin[2 t])^2], 
 ArcTan[0. + 0.75764 t - 0.615051 Sin[2 t], 
  0. + 0.429824 t + 0.218389 Sin[2 t]], 
 0. - 0.491154 t - 0.75764 Sin[2 t]} 

I want to find where the first component is equal to any of the values from the following list:
list = {3.10, 5.05, 8.85, 12.25}~Join~{29.9, 37.1, 44.3, 51.4}

I know that there could be multiple solutions for t for each value in the list, so to find all the solutions I make a table of tables of solutions with FindRoot (with the intention of deleting duplicate solutions later), where I increment both the starting guess for t = t0, and the value from List.
 NumTimesteps = 15;
timeStep = 1;
IntersectionTimes = 
  Table[Table[FindRoot[function[[1]] - List[[i]], {t, timeStep j, 0, Infinity}], {i, 1,Length[list]}], {j, 0, NumTimesteps}];
IntersectionPoints = Table[function /. IntersectionTimes[[i]], {i, 1, 
    Length[IntersectionTimes]}]; 
UniqueIntersectionPoints = DeleteDuplicates[SetPrecision[IntersectionPoints, 5]] // MatrixForm

This code finds a list of t values using FindRoot that satisfies:
function[[1]] - list[[i]]

And to the best of my knowledge, if we plug those t values back into our function, then the first component of every 3 component vector function(t) should give a value in the List. However this is not the case. MOST of the first components are in the list, but notice in the output there is a first component of function(t) of 2.7361, which is NOT in the list. Further, the last line does not seem to delete duplicates. These bugs happen every time I generate my random function. Anyone know what is going on here??[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I was ultimately able so solve this problem by using NSolve instead of FindRoot.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/82sbcxJT.png

There is a syntax error in the definition of function. Until that is fixed we would have to guess what you intended.

List =... gives me an error.

If I uncapitalized all the variables, it seems to work for me: https://i.sstatic.net/JpW7wEI2.png

Your start values for FindRoot will not achieve what you want.
Consider a plot of the first component of "function" together with the values of "list" (note: your function has 2 and not 3 components. Further "List" is a reserved word, use "list"):
 function = {Sqrt[(0. + 0.75764 t - 0.615051 Sin[2 t])^2 + (0. + 0.429824 t +  0.218389 Sin[2 t])^2], ArcTan[0. + 0.75764 t - 0.615051 Sin[2 t], 0. + 0.429824 t + 0.218389 Sin[2 t]], 
 0. - 0.491154 t - 0.75764 Sin[2 t]} ;
list = {3.10, 5.05, 8.85, 12.25}~Join~{29.9, 37.1, 44.3, 51.4}
xm = 80;
Plot[function[[1]], {t, -xm, xm}, 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{-xm, #}, {xm, #}}] & /@ list}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, Max[list]}]


Note that the curve is symmetrical around t==0. And it has an approximative  slope of +/- 0.86. Further analysis of this curve reveals only 2 intersections (+/-) of the curve with each y value. This makes things easier, Otherwise you would have to search for multiple crossings.
Therefore, we may choose the starting values for "FindRoot" to be: y-value/slope. This gives a list with the positive t values for the intersections:
slope = 0.86;
tvals= t /. Table[FindRoot[function[[1]] - list[[i]], {t, list[[i]]/slope}], {i,8}]

{3.99967, 5.31518, 10.5384, 14.0997, 33.8343, 42.5024, 51.2898,58.6025}

To check if this are right, we may calculate the errors by:
(function[[1]] /. t -> tvals) - list

{4.44089*10^-16, -8.88178*10^-16, 0., 1.77636*10^-15, 0., 0., 0., -7.10543*10^-15}

Finally, to get all the t values, we add the negative values:
Join[-Reverse@tvals, tvals]

{-58.6025, -51.2898, -42.5024, -33.8343, -14.0997, -10.5384, -5.31518, -3.99967, 3.99967, 5.31518, 10.5384, 14.0997, 33.8343, 42.5024, 51.2898, 58.6025}

Now that we have all t values, you may create the final table. I leave this as an exercise to you.

Was the definition of function edited? my plot of function[[1]] is not the same

You are right, I do not know what happened, but the slope is now larger. However, the  method is still valid. I fixed this in the answer.

Unfortunately this didn't work for me since I did need to look for multiple zero crossings.  I should have specified that I was randomly generating parameters to my function, so the number of crossings is parameter dependent, so sometimes there are multiple crossings.
Also, if my function only has 2 components, then why is it that if I plug in a value for t that it returns something with three components?

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Change the definition of function to include its argument.
function[t_] = {Sqrt[(0. + 0.75764  t - 0.615051  Sin[2  t])^2 + (0. + 
          0.429824  t + 0.218389  Sin[2  t])^2], 
     ArcTan[0. + 0.75764  t - 0.615051  Sin[2  t], 
      0. + 0.429824  t + 0.218389  Sin[2  t]], 
     0. - 0.491154  t - 0.75764  Sin[2  t]} // Rationalize[#, 0] & // 
   Simplify;

list = {3.10, 5.05, 8.85, 12.25}~Join~{29.9, 37.1, 44.3, 51.4} // Rationalize;

Without assuming symmetry or the number of solutions per list value
(sol = {#, Solve[function[t][[1]] == #, t, Reals]} & /@
    list) // N

(* {{3.1, {{t -> -3.99967}, {t -> 3.99967}}}, 
    {5.05, {{t -> -5.31518}, {t -> 5.31518}}}, 
    {8.85, {{t -> -10.5384}, {t -> 10.5384}}}, 
    {12.25, {{t -> -14.0997}, {t -> 14.0997}}}, 
    {29.9, {{t -> -33.8343}, {t -> 33.8343}}}, 
    {37.1, {{t -> -42.5024}, {t -> 42.5024}}}, 
    {44.3, {{t -> -51.2898}, {t -> 51.2898}}}, 
    {51.4, {{t -> -58.6025}, {t -> 58.6025}}}} *)

Checking results
(And @@ Thread[#[[1]] == function[t][[1]] /. #[[2]]]) & /@ sol // N

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)

